# urdfdom_model problem

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I just followed the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20urdf%20file , but when I typed

$ rosrun urdfdom_model check_urdf my_urdf.xml

```
  in the terminal, it displays:
```

[rospack] Error: stack/package urdfdom_model not found

```
  Do you know why?

  I highly appreciate your time and great help!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57639/urdfdom_model-problem/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do need to have ros-groovy-urdfdom

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-urdfdom
```

Than you just need to execute

```
rosrun urdfdom check_urdf my_urdf.xml
```

you dont need the urdfdom_model

And finally, when you are going to convert it to pdf, you do

```
rosrun urdfdom urdf_to_graphiz my_urdf.xml
```

---

Originally posted by [Amarante](https://answers.ros.org/users/4583/amarante/) with karma: 31 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using Fuerte, you should try the command

```
rosrun urdf_parser check_urdf my_urdf.xml
```

Apparently much of the urdf functionality is moved into the urdfdom package in Groovy.  See the note on [this page.](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf_parser)  If you are using Groovy, perhaps you are missing the `ros-groovy-urdfdom` package.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2